# how do I use javascript to create a table?

Tags: javascript

I know that this has been covered in a couple of different ways, but my understanding of Javascript is still very basic and I can't seem to understand how to implement the solutions that I find, so I am asking. I have a hidden div. I want to take the elements from a form, then use them to create a cost estimation table. I can follow the variables in the console, so I know that they are defined and work correctly. Here is what I have:

```
<div class="results_box" id="control_box">
       <div id="invoice_box">

       </div>
      </div>`
```

and

```
unction displayResults(batting, delivery) {
var box=document.getElementById("control_box");
var invoice=document.getElementById('invoice_box');
invoice.append('<table><tr><td>Quilt size in inches:</td><td> + size + </td></tr><tr><td>Cost per square inch:</td><td> + patCost + </td></tr><tr><td>Cost of batting:</td><td> + batting + </td></tr><tr><td>Shipping and handling:</td><td> + delivery +</td></tr><tr><td>Total Cost:</td><td></td></tr></table<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="basic-submit">Contact me about this estimate</button>');
displayResults(box.style.display="block");
```

}

here is the call

```
displayResults(batting, delivery);
```

Most of the variables are global, but those 2 are local. This fails, and I am sure that you can tell me why, but the page reloads and the console resets before I can see the error message, so I can't even tell what I should be trying to fix. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Your Javascript has so many errors I don't know where to begin. You have no Concatination, broken HTML tags, a basic misunderstanding of the `append` function. I suggest you take a step back and learn the basics.

Comment: `.append(HTMLstring)` is a jQuery function anyway. Once you solve the other problems, you want `invoice.innerHTML = '<table>...</table>';`

Comment: why do you call `displayResults(box.style.display="block");` at the end?

Comment: \I call the box at the end to display 'block' because I want it hidden until after the form is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.createElement('table')` and append `childNodes(tr th and td )` and add `textNodes` to the td element( or other elements )